# iOS - How to use opengl to draw different screen on iphone and apple TV?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Currently, I want to develop a small game like car racing. In the game, user will use iphone as a gamepad and apple tv will be display the main screen of gameplay. That means user control the car using iphone and the actual gameplay drawing will be presented on external display (AppleTV).

I have found an article here to detect and use external screen:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012555-CH3-SW1

But I haven't found and sample of using opengl es to render on different display at the same time.

Anyone helps, Many Thanks